# TypeScript VSCode global imports don't work

Tags: typescript, import, tsconfig

I need to use the js `file system` in my TypeScript project (and others too).
For that reason I wrote at the top of my file as I read multiple times online:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

But this gives me now this error:

```
Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

I read online that I need to specifiy this in my `tsconfig.json` so I added this:

```json
{
  "other functioning": "configs",
  "include": ["C:/Users/Flori/node_modules/@types/node"]
}
```

but that didn't work even though in this folder is actually a file called `fs.d.ts`...

`"C:/Users/Flori/node_modules/@types/node/*.d.ts"` didn't work either

aswell as `"node_modules/@types/node/*.d.ts"`

or `"node_modules/@types/node/**.*"`...

**My code does compile actually if I type `// @ts-nocheck` at the top, and I can use `fs.readFile()` with expected results.**

(I tried `"moduleResolution": "node"` in the `compilerOptions` of `tsconfig` too, but it didn't fix the issue.)

(`npm install @types/node --save-dev` is not an option, as I dont want the node folder, which is bad with github and other dependencies)